# Failure to stop executing task in Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I just installed Xcode 4.3 and I'm having some issues with stopping my app while running in the iOS simulator. I'm able to quit the simulator, but I cannot stop the task from running, either by hitting the stop button, or using the keybinding. In order to stop the process, I literally have to quit Xcode and restart. This obviously makes any development at all very difficult. I found this bugreport: [link](http://openradar.appspot.com/10970285), which sounds very similar to the issue I'm seeing.

Is this a known issue with 4.3, or has anyone else experienced this behavior? I haven't used Xcode for over a year now (v3), so I can't say if it was working with any other previous versions of Xcode 4.

Comment: The same thing happens if you exit a MacOSX application that you're developing while the debugger is watching it. Must remember to stop debugging from within Xcode, not by quitting the app.

Comment: Another way to have this issue occur: Launch the simulator while Xcode is closed, then open Xcode. Tell it to launch in the simulator. It'll fail to launch, but it'll act like it did launch and refuse to stop the non-started task.

Comment: You should mark @yeahdixon's answer below as the solution.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Found this post helpful
[XCode 4.3.2, issue with running on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168922/xcode-4-3-2-issue-with-running-on-simulator)

Strangely when it hangs, **click on the simulator icon in the tray**. Dont ask me why. This actually works

Comment: f***ing amazing (and WTF!) Thank you, you have just save me hundreds of hours in the future!!

Comment: it brings me a perverse joy to use this handy workaround.  it's a little bit like having my soul healed for all the times Xcode has rended it in the past.  i click on the simulator icon in the Dock, and then i laugh, and i laugh, and i laugh.

Comment: yeahdixon, you're powerful

Comment: I regret I didn't find this earlier.

Answer (score 16):

I can confirm this is still the case with Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion, unfortunately.

If I close the iOS simulator with Cmd+Q rather than leaving it open and stopping the simulation with the "Stop" button on the Xcode toolbar, the following things happen (although not systematically, but in 25% of the cases launching the same application - I believe this is related to application status but I have not understood how yet):

- the "run" button in Xcode does not open a new iOS Simulator session; the "stop" button is still clickable but gives no result;
- the toolbar continues to say "Running on iPhone simulator" no matter how many times you click "Stop";
- if the iOS simulator is launched manually, it is not linked to the Xcode session;
- not only does one have to re-start XCode: the restart has to be *forced* as the simple Xcode "Quit" command will not work.

Comment: Exactly the same here. I've had this issue on Lion and Xcode 4.3. But it seems to be worse on Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.4.
I guess I have to get used to stop the app from Xcode and give the cmd+q thing up! ;)

Comment: did anyone filed a rdar for this ?

Answer (score 8):

I've noticed this a lot since updating. The cure seems to be to just try to remember to stop the application from within Xcode while the simulator is still running the app. It seems like when you kill the simulator out from under Xcode your simulator process hangs and doesn't pass the termination message on to Xcode like it is supposed to.

Comment: I've been doing the same thing, it usually closes fine if I stop it from Xcode, but quitting the simulator definitely causes it to hang.

Comment: Well I hope this helped because it isn't a problem only you are experiencing. Maybe this will be fixed in 4.3.2 but for now it just seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a solution, but I just overrode the “Quit iOS Simulator” keyboard shortcut in System Preferences to something I’m unlikely to type impulsively, like ⌘⌥Q.

Comment: This looks like the only solution, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar problem which can be resolved by restarting Xcode, but it's quite annoying. I've managed to get a workaround for this 'problem'.

1. Go to `~/Applications/` and open the context menu for Xcode.app and select `Show Package Contents`
2. Navigate to `/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/`
3. Copy `iOS Simulator.app` and paste it to (for instance) your Desktop
4. Next start your OSX system preferences panel and navigate to `Keyboard`
5. Select the second tab `Keyboard Shortcuts`
6. Select `Application Shortcuts` on the left side
7. Press the small `+` sign on the right side
8. A small dialog appears.
   Select the copied `iOS Simulator.app` in the first selectbox > `Other...`
9. As `Menu Title` fill in `Home`
10. And for the menu shortcut 'type' `COMMAND + Q`
11. Now hit `Add` and close your system preferences
12. Delete `iOS Simulator.app` from your Desktop.

If you now start the simulator through Xcode and (accidentally) want to quit the simulator while it's running and attached to Xcode > you can't.

I know it doesn't fix the problem itself, but for those pro-users who use keyboard shortcuts for everything this might help a bit.

Comment: Can this somehow be modified to call Xcode's stop button instead?