# Why does Xcode 4.3.1 (4E1019) / 4.3.2 (4E2002) hang regularly with iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-lion

Once in every 10-20 runs I experience a hanging Xcode when trying to start a new App run in the simulator. The App won't start.

I can quit the simulator, but Xcode will simply ignore quits.

The only solution so far is to kill and restart Xcode. Fortunately that seems to work without side effects.

(xcode 4.3 on Lion, 8GB mac mini, 5.1 iOS)

Edit: I filed a bug report with Apple.

Edit June 2012: it's still a problem in Xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002)

Edit October 2012: with Xcode 4.5 this issue seems to have gone away. I do seem to notice that every run on the simulator now has a pause of a few seconds before starting the application. Perhaps the issue was fixed by introducing a longer wait somewhere. (There is no such thing as a free lunch.)

Comment: I've been experiencing something similar, often it seems that starting a build (cmd-B) during the "hang" gets you moving again. you then end up with two sessions running in the stop button dropdown, one of which isn't real. It's pretty poor.

Comment: Indeed you can still do a build (cmd-B), but even with a simulator that was quitted Xcode thinks the simulator is "in use".

Comment: This may just be the nature of the beast. For the most part, XCode is rather nice to develop in but it seems to get caught on odd things and/or simply crashes. Have you updated to 4.3.1?

Comment: Yes, this is Version 4.3.1 (4E1019).

Comment: Problem still occur on Moutain Lion (10.8) with Xcode Version 4.4.1 (4F1003)

Comment: Still happening for me on XCode 4.6.  Actually seems more frequent now than on 4.5.

Answer (score 6):

Found a workaround that saves you killing Xcode when this happens: if a hang occurs when you are running the iPhone simulator switch to iPad simulator, or vice versa. You will get the message that the simulator is already in use, but ignore that. Then switch back to the device simulator that caused your trouble in the first place, a new run will work!

Perhaps Xcode has trouble contacting the running process in the simulator, above workaround helps.

Comment: I too have found that this helps but not always

Answer (score 4):

i have found that the hang is harder than all that.  can't even get in to switch simulators.  Quit Xcode won't work because it doesn't want to stop all tasks.  tried killing a zombied clang task, but that didn't work.  didn't see either gdb or lldb tasks, though i know clang is associated with lldb.

so ... no answer except force quit xcode or kill -9 xcode processes in terminal.

**update** … try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277189/774691 (which is also referred to by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400190/774691 ) !  it's impossible to believe it works, but i use this 2-3 times a day, and i laugh and i laugh and i laugh.  it's insane, but it works.  vote it up.  the guy who came up with that answer needs some serious upvotes!

Comment: I agree. I have tried all the suggested answers for this question, and none of them work. The only solution is to kill xcode. I am using xcode 4.6

Answer (score 3):

Use GDB instead of LLDB (default) for debugging. There are some bugs in LLDB right now affecting launch hangs, false memory address readouts, uncaught breakpoints resulting in EXC_BREAKPOINT kills).

Comment: Thanks, I checked, but GDB already is the debugger, not LLDB.

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and quickly press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and it will run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this a lot. Every time I start XCode, I get one run and then after that if I try to run again (after Command-Q in the simulator) I have to Force Quit XCode if I want to run again. I can see running simulator processes with ps -ef, but even if I kill them (and they die), XCode still believes there's a simulator running.

I'm having **some success** with performing iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... before I quit the simulator. I'm also having some success with Stopping the simulator (from XCode) as soon as I've finished testing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that stopping the App  currently running in the simulator before new compiling-run solve the problem : <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Moutain Lion (10.8) + Xcode Version 4.4.1 (4F1003)

Answer (score 0):

I reported it to apple

```
BUG REPORT
12872744

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/175685
```

You can also restart the Simulator and restart the app manually and this wakes XCode up and it  leaves the stuck DEBUG mode and goes back to STOP mode.

You have to start the run in Xcode again but at least its stopped hanging.