# Xcode 4.3.2, issue with running on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been having this weird problem with Xcode 4.3.2, of course after the recent update.

After successfully building and running on the simulator several times, xcode seems to not be able to connect to the simulator and can't even stop the project; it's like the simulator does not exist. I have tried:

1. Stopping the project – doesn't work.
2. Quitting the simulator – doesn't work, xcode still shows it's running on the simulator even when I quit the simulator.
3. Cleaning the project – doesn't work.

I have to force quit xcode to get it communicate with the simulator. Nothing else works. It gets quite frustrating to do it every half an hour. This only started with 4.3.2.

I always stop before building and running, so it is not an issue of simulator/xcode getting thrashed by me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This happens to me occasionally too, I haven't found a cure, I think it's just a bug in this latest release.

Comment: If it's occasional i might be able to live with it, for me its more like once in every 10 times i try to build/run on the simulator. And CodaFi, am sure you wont be very happy restarting your mac every half an hour!

Comment: What I find is the if you don't kill the process between builds and runs, it duplicates itself in the sim and then the sim hangs.

Comment: Are you pressing stop before running the project again?  If not try doing that...I can't remember ever having this problem with the same version of XCode ^^;

Comment: As i mentioned in the original post, i am definitely practicing stopping before running again. So i don't think that is an issue.

Comment: Apple needs to seriously fix this. It is SO annoying. Specially when you have several projects running, you have to kill them all!

Comment: This appears to be resolved as of Xcode 4.6.2.

Comment: nope. this is not fixed in xcode 4.6.2

Comment: It seems this still happens.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I have found by chance, it is not a solution by any means -

When xcode hangs, saying it is running the app, but nothing is on simulator, opening the simulator from the dock by clicking on the dock icon (not using command+tab) seems to work.

It is very weird,but it works; atelast till xcode fixes it.

Comment: thanks!! at last found a workaround for a bug that's sometimes very annoying

Comment: This is the best iOS-related development advice I've ever get. :)

Comment: Brilliant. Had this issue so many times the last weeks and restarting Xcode every time is very annoying.

Comment: I have been frustrated with the simulator unable to see anything on TCP/IP, including the Safari app. This work around is helping. I can get about 3 or 4 debugging sessions in before the network stops responding. This is new for me with 4.6.3.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same damn issue on XCode 4.5.1, but I resolved it just now.
When the program is running, it gets compiled but doesn't show anything on the simulator. just click on iOS Simulator icon in dock in order to bring it to front. Click **iOS Simulator** on top left -> Reset content and settings -> then force quit the iOS Simulator and run the program again. !!

Answer (score 2):

Besides a restart, there is one other way I've managed to get around this:

Let's say your app hangs, go to the targets selector in the top of the Xcode window and change your sim target to a new SDK (or if you don't have another SDK, change it to a universal app and run on the opposite device simulator).

Then, when your app loads on the new device/OS completely, quit the sim, change your targets back, et voilà!

Comment: Thanks for the tip codafi, but i was hoping i dont have to do that every now and then. That would definitely put a dent in my productivity. I was hoping there is some solution out there, that fixes xcode itself.

Comment: @CodaFi, this used to work for me up through Xcode 4.5.2, but i think i have found that it no longer works in Xcode 4.6 .  does it still work for you?

Comment: @john.k.doe I've noticed it no longer works in Xcode 5 as well. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall application from Simulator and again run.  Then it will works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

This has frustrated me for -years- now but stumbled across what appears to get things going again for me:

Hide the simulator (iOS Simulator -> Hide iOS Simulator) or Cmd-H, then reopen the simulator.

The problem seems to happen when something CPU intensive is happening in the background (like a Time Machine backup) on my old 2 core MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.6.3 update (June 13, 2013) resolves the following issue:

- Hang when debugging in iOS Simulator on OS X 10.8.4. 13722320

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/

You can try to update your Xcode to see if that works for you..