# Can't stop Xcode app execution in simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

Has anyone seen this before?  Ever since I upgraded to Xcode 4.5.2, sometimes when I press Command-R to run an app in the simulator, the status in Xcode says "Running", but the app never starts in the simulator.  When I press Command-., it says it is trying to stop, but never stops.  Xcode basically is hung, I have to force quit.  Hopefully there is a simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tends to work.  I use Serge's find to click the icon in the dock - this then "wakes up" XCode to the fact that it needs to attach to the app in the simulator.  Even though the attach never happens, a Command-Period at this point stops XCode without hanging it and having to do a Force Quit.  Then, I can close down the Simulator, and do Command-R to run from XCode.  This relaunches the simulator and attaches to the app process.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the simulator and deleting the application. Also try closing and re opening xcode. If this does not try restarting your computer. If you are still having the problem then you will have to uninstall xcode and reinstall it. (I have had that problem multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but works. Click on the 'iOS Simulator' icon in the Dock (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277189/1514970).