# Xcode 5.0.2 black screen simulator on app launch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

First of all I have tried almost many possible solutions in stack overflow,say  one like this [Xcode /Sim black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168922/xcode-4-3-2-issue-with-running-on-simulator)But my problem is still not solved! I cannot run my app in any of my sims in Xcode 5.0.2/OS X 10.9.1 . Like many others my problem is when I launch an app the Xcode shows an indefinite processing message like "Attaching to AppName" and meanwhile shows a Black screen simulator.

1. I had reset my sim/mac.
2. Cleaned device driver directory.
3. Checked    bundle identifiers

But the problem still exists.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I always have to wait upon to 1 min when I launch my app the first time on the simulator. So you have to wait and then the app will start.

Comment: Well i waited for many mins and in vain

Comment: But the project work when build and run it in my iDevice but not in sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution in Apple discussion forums. Added `127.0.0.1 localhost` to my etc/hosts file. Now Xcode can attach app to simulator.Got this answer from [FMLZ's thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23838409#23838409) in Apple discussion forum.